# Down Casting ID3D11Texture2D

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

According to the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476635(v=vs.85).aspx

ID3D11Texture2D inherits from the  ID3D11Resource.

I tried the following but it gives a std:non-rtti exception.

```
ID3D11Texture2D *tex2d = dynamic_cast<ID3D11Texture2D*>(resource);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `ID3D11Texture2D` is a COM interface you should use `QueryInterface` to get other interfaces the object might support. Something like this:

```
HRESULT hr = resource->QueryInterface(IID_ID3D11Texture2D, (void **) &tex2d);
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    // handle failure here.
}
```

Note this still can still fail if the object pointed to by `resource` doesn't implement the `ID3D11Texture2D` interface, that is, it's not a 2D texture resource.

Strictly speaking you should also be using `QueryInterface` to "up cast" `ID3D11Texture2D` interfaces to `ID3D11Resource` interfaces. COM doesn't require that if an object implements a derived interface that it also implement the base interface. However up casting should work with any Direct3D COM interface.

Comment: Up-casting is safe with Direct3D because they are implemented as inherited C++ classes, which require that works.

Answer (score 0):

Its unneccessary to Use Queryinterface if you know what type of Resource it is.

```
ID3D11Texture2D* ptx = NULL;
resource->GetResource(reinterpret_cast<ID3D11Resource**>(&ptx));
```

Though if the rviews contains a varity of types Query i needed.